# Assign multiple selectors to variable based on which one exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm looping through a container and looking for possible elements that exist. If the one of the elements exist, I want to assign the jQuery object for the element to a variable. I have a solution, but I'm not sure if it's a good way to go about it.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div>
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label>last name</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label>location</label>
    <select>
        <option>USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var testNum = $('form').find('label').length;
for(var i=0; i<testNum; i++) {
    var currentTest = $('form').find('label').eq(i).parent().find('input').length ? $('form').find('label').eq(i) : false || $('form').find('label').eq(i).parent().find('select').length ? $('form').find('label').eq(i) : false;
    $('html').append(currentTest.text() + '<br/>');
}
});
```

**edit: updated fiddle and problem**

http://jsfiddle.net/PMtZB/1/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The way you are looping is inefficient. You should use the `.each()` method, like this:

```
$('form').find('label').each(function() {
    var $label = $(this); // $label is a jQuery object that refers to the label element.


    ...
});
```

The way you are doing it, you are repeatedly calling `.find()` for the same selector.

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION WAS EDITED:**

Two things first:

1. It would be helpful if you stated what elements you wanted in words, not just with code. I will assume you want all `<label>` elements that are followed by either an `<input>` or a `<select>`.
2. You should use parentheses. I looked it up, and the logical-or operator has a higher precedence than the conditional operator, and the conditional operator has right-to-left associativity. I think you need to add parentheses so your statement looks like this: `(c1 ? a1 : a2) || (c2 ? b1 : b2)`. Without parentheses, you have the equivalent of `c1 ? a1 : ((a2 || c2) ? b1 : b2)`.

You could try adding on to what K D suggested and concatenate a jQuery wrapped set:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $matchingLabels = $();

    $('form').find('label').each(function() {
        var $label = $(this);
        if ($label.next().is('input, select')) {
            $matchingLabels.add($label);
        }
    });

    // At this point $matchingLabels holds the labels you want.
});
```

You could also try using the "prev + next" selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $matchingLabels = $('form').find('label + input, label + select').prev();

});
```

Of course, if you can't assume that the `<input>` and `<select>` elements always immediately follow the `<label>` elements, you will have to go with the first option and modify the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var testNum = $('form').find('label').length;

    $('form').find('label').each(function(){
        if($(this).next().is("input") || $(this).next().is("select"))
        {
           $('html').append($(this).text() + '<br/>');
        }
    });

});
```

**Paste this code into your fiddle and test..**

Comment: This will output the same thing as my code and is much cleaner, but isn't really what I'm looking for. I need to check to see if an element exists, and if it does, I need to set currentTest as a selector for that element. My example code doesn't do that because I tried to simplify the problem and didn't realize that I went too far doing that. I'll edit my question.